# cancel button should refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a cancel button it should not update the data into database and it should refresh my page,but in my case page is not refreshing

```
<Button onClick={() => searchDiagnosisCode()}>Cancel</Button>
 const searchDiagnosisCode = () => {
props.setConfirm(true);
setTimeout(function () {
  props.history.push({
    pathname: '/DiagnosisCodeSearch',
    editPage: true,
  });
}, 10);
```

};

Comment: this code is not enough to understand the problem and help you out. How exactly do you refresh the page ?

Answer (score 1):

try `window.location.reload();` to refresh the page

```
<Button onClick={() => searchDiagnosisCode()}>Cancel</Button>

const searchDiagnosisCode = () => {
 props.setConfirm(true);
 setTimeout(function () {
   window.location.reload();
}, 10);
```